# How to identify if a page of PDF contains text using PyPDF2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

The original task is to crop a PDF to several seperated parts.
I have adjusted some params to complete the task,but sometimes,
my croping method will lead to a 'blank page' that just looks like,it has a text(using extractText method).
So I want to know how to filter the 'blank page' that mentioned above.

Below is part of my croping method:

```
original = 'input.pdf'
target = 'output.pdf'
pdf = PdfFileReader(open(original, 'rb'))
for page in pdf.pages:
    for i in range(4):
        new_page = copy.copy(page)
        if i == 0:
            # TOP LEFT
            new_page.mediaBox.upperRight = (285.5, 780)
            new_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (20, 570)
        elif i == 1:
            # BOTTOM LEFT
            new_page.mediaBox.upperRight = (285.5, 400)
            new_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (20, 190)
        elif i == 2:
            # TOP RIGHT
            new_page.mediaBox.upperRight = (572, 780)
            new_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (306.5, 570)
        elif i == 3:
            # BOTTOM RIGHT
            new_page.mediaBox.upperRight = (572, 400)
            new_page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = (306.5, 190)
        out.addPage(new_page)


with open(target, 'wb') as f:
    out.write(f)
```

Here is croped PDF: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxL6yv_HDnNYMEt0OF9RU1BaYWM